# how to redirect to next page in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created four different pages in react and added them using react router?
I want to make redirect the profile page to home page if user is not logged in.
I have tried following code.

`<Route path="/profile" {login ? <Profile /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />} />`

( "/" is home page )

Comment: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

the docs has example literally for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close to correct, but not quite. You're trying to put your `Profile` or `Redirect` tags inside the tag itself for the route, but that won't yield a valid structure. You need to make them a *child* of the `Route` tag. See below:

Before:

```
<Route path="/profile" {login ? <Profile /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />} />
```

After:

```
<Route path="/profile">
    {login ? <Profile /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />}
</Route>
```

There's a good example of the exact behaviour you're looking for on the React Router docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

```
<Route path="/profile" {login ? <Profile /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />} />
```

The above code isn't rendering any routed content on the `element` prop.

## Solution

The `react-router-dom@6` `Route` API requires the routed content to be rendered on the `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/profile"
  element={login ? <Profile /> : <Navigate replace to="/" />}
/>
```

This is a common enough pattern of route protection that it's recommended to create and use layout routes that render an `Outlet` component so you can wrap and protect groups of routes with a single auth wrapper.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  // auth logic
  return auth
    ? <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
  <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} /> // <-- rendered into Outlet
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
```